# String literal is not properly executing

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Please help, what should i do about the error? I got error in "In Helper executing" and it says "String literal is not properly closed by a double quote."

```
public class SMS extends Activity {
//
   public static final String DEBUG_TAG = "FullDatabase Log"; 
   public static final int DB_version = 2; 
   //public static final String DB_name = "User.db"; 
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "login"; 
   //public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_temp"; 
   //public static final String DB_name = "User_temp"; 
   public static final String DBNAME = "login"; 
   public DatabaseHelper database_helper; 
   public SQLiteDatabase database; 
   public SQLiteDatabase database_rd; 
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
   public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
   super.onCreate1(savedInstanceState); 
   setContentView(R.layout.main); 
   Toast.makeText(this,"Before Bundled", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   createDataBase(); 
   //LogIn login = new LogIn(); 
   Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget71); 
   Toast.makeText(this,"after Bundled", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   { 
                   @Override 
                   public void onClick(View v) { 
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            SMS createaccount = new SMS(); 
            Toast.makeText(createaccount.getApplicationContext(), "In Helper executing 
            onCreate1()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                           String[] success = insertRecords(); 
                           if(success[0].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
                           { 
                             Intent mIntent = new Intent(LogIn.this,DisplayUser.class); 
                                   mIntent.putExtra("username",success[1]); 
                                   mIntent.putExtra("retype",success[2]); 
                                   mIntent.putExtra("password",success[3]);  
                                   startActivity(mIntent); 
                           } 
                   } 
           }); 
   //database.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly, and show the real error message - don't paraphrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java strings cannot span multiple lines. Change

```
Toast.makeText(createaccount.getApplicationContext(), "In Helper executing 
            onCreate1()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(createaccount.getApplicationContext(), "In Helper executing onCreate1()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a compile time error.  You broke your string across two lines (Unless the listing you show is being wrapped).  If you want the string on two line, make it two strings
"this is the beginning"
+ " and this is the end."